# How to Allow Special Characters(#,@,!,&,(,),%) as search keyword in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I have got struck with the implementation of allowing Special Characters(#,@,!,&,(,),%) as search keyword in Sphinx..

Please suggest me..

Below is the config file,

/* Starts */

```
source dbserver
{
    type                    =   mysql
    sql_host                =   localhost
    sql_user                =   root
    sql_pass                =   
    sql_db                  =   mydb
    #sql_sock               =   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    sql_port                =   3306 
}


searchd
{
    listen                  =   localhost:3312
    # port                  =   9313
    log                     =                       /* some searchd.log path */
    query_log               =                   /* some query.log path */
    pid_file                =                   /* some searchd.pid path */
    max_matches             =   10000
    seamless_rotate         =   0
}


source  adsearch : mydbserver
{
    sql_query_post          = REPLACE INTO sph_tracker SELECT 1,'ad',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

    sql_ranged_throttle     = 1
    sql_attr_uint           = networkid
    sql_attr_uint           = folderid
    sql_attr_uint           = createdby
    sql_attr_uint           = status
    sql_attr_timestamp      = createdon
}

index index_adsearch
{
    source                  = adsearch
    path                    =           /* some path */
    morphology              = stem_en
    min_word_len            = 0
    #min_prefix_len         = 5
    min_infix_len           = 2
    enable_star             = 1
    preopen                 = 1
}

source delta_adsearch : adsearch
{
    sql_query   = DELETE FROM ad where status='Deleted' AND deleteflag='Y'                              
}

index delta_index_adsearch : index_adsearch
{
    source                  = delta_adsearch
    path                    =               /* some path */
}

source  tmplsearch : mydbserver
{
     sql_query_post         = REPLACE INTO sph_tracker SELECT 2,'template',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;


    sql_ranged_throttle     = 1
    sql_attr_uint           = networkid
    sql_attr_uint           = industryid
    sql_attr_uint           = status
    sql_attr_timestamp      = createdon
    sql_attr_timestamp      = startdate
    sql_attr_timestamp      = enddate
    sql_attr_uint           = active
    sql_attr_uint   = primarysize
}

index index_tmplsearch
{
    source                  = tmplsearch
    path                    =               /* some path */
    morphology              = stem_en
    min_word_len            = 0
    #min_prefix_len         = 5
    min_infix_len           = 2
    enable_star             = 1
    preopen                 = 1
}

source delta_tmplsearch : tmplsearch
{
    sql_query   = DELETE FROM adtemplate where status='Deleted' AND deleteflag='Y'                              
}

index delta_index_tmplsearch : index_tmplsearch
{
    source                  = delta_tmplsearch
    path                    =               /* some path */
}


source  media_assets_search : mydbserver
{   
    #sql_query_post         = REPLACE INTO sph_tracker SELECT 3,'media',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

    sql_ranged_throttle     = 1
    sql_attr_uint           = networkid
    sql_attr_uint           = mediatype
    sql_attr_uint           = mediacat
    sql_attr_uint           = uploadedby
    sql_attr_uint           = active    
    sql_attr_uint           = industryid        
    sql_attr_timestamp      = uploaddate
    sql_attr_uint           = diskstore
}

index index_media_assets_search
{
    source                  = media_assets_search
    path                    =               /* some path */
    morphology              = stem_en
    min_word_len            = 0
    #min_prefix_len         = 5
    min_infix_len           = 2
    enable_star             = 1
    preopen                 = 1
}

source delta_media_assets_search : media_assets_search
{

}

index delta_index_media_assets_search : index_media_assets_search
{
    source                  = delta_media_assets_search
    path                    =                   /* some path */
}
```

/* Ends */

Please have a look at this and suggest me..

Thanks,

Nagu..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add them to charset_table config.

You may also want to make sure you escape the query to avoid being misinterpreted as search syntax.

While there do also read up on blend_chars

Comment: Thanks Barry.., 
But in my config file, there is no charset_table defined. So how can i do. I am trying to paste that config file code with this comment..but here it is not taking, showing as too long by 4941 characters.. and here i didnt get an upload file option also. Can you please suggest me.

Comment: If you dont have one, you can just add one. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table  Can just edit your question, SO is kinda like a wiki, to add your config if you really need to share it.

Comment: Hello Barry..,
I have edited my question with config file code. Please have a look at and suggest me.

Thanks,
Nagu.

Comment: Well you dont have a charset_table in there, so you need to add one. My last comment already included a direct link to the documentation, if you hadnt found it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Barry. As u said I have the charset_type,charset_table to index_adsearch as below. but it is not working.can u suggest.

index index_adsearch
{
    source                  = adsearch
    path                    = /cotserver/includes/searchengine/sphinx/data/index_adsearch
    morphology              = stem_en
 min_word_len            = 0
    #min_prefix_len         = 5
    min_infix_len           = 2
 enable_star    = 1
 preopen     = 1
 charset_type = utf-8
 charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, -, @, #, $, a..z, U+0021..U+0029, U+002B..U+002F,U+003A..U+0040, U+007B, U+007C,   U+007D
}

Comment: Have you got any solution? I am having similar problem. Doesn't work even after adding the charset_table.